# Angular - How can I mock an external function in a unit test?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to write an angular unit test for a function that has a dependency on an imported function - how can write a unit test that mocks the results of the imported function? The function I have is:

```
import { DependentMethod } from './dependentMethod';

export function doSomething() {
  const dependentResults = DependentMethod(); // DependentMethod makes an http call and returns the result
  return dependentResults;
}
```

In this case, I want to test the `doSomething` and mock the `DependentMethod` function. When I've tried to mock stuff before, I've used `spy` on class methods but I'm not sure how to handle it in this case. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In your `component.spec.ts` file import the whole library:

```
import * as dependentMethodLibrary from './dependentMethodLibrary';
```

After that in your `describe` or `it` block, mock the function of the library:

```
spyOn(dependentMethodLibrary, 'DependentMethod').and.returnValue({});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try something as below,

```
import { dependent } from './dependentLibrary'; 


describe('yourCoponent', () => {
  let component: yourComponent;
  let service : dependentService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    service = new dependent(null); // if your service has further dependency
    component = new yourComponent(service);
  });

  it('should perform test', () => {
    // Arrange part --> 
    spyOn(service, 'dependentMethod').and.callFake(() => {
      return Observable.from([ [1,2,3] ]); // return your mock data
    });

    //Act part
    component.ngOnInit();

    //Assert
    expect(component.testable.action).toBe(value);

  });
```